# Generic return types in a singly linked list

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I'm working on a program that works with a linked list of generic objects, inside the class that defines a single list there is a method that returns the value of that link:

```
 public class Link<E> {
      private E _value;

      public E getValue() {
           return _value;
      }
```

Then I want to use this return value of type < E > in the linked link class to return the value of a link at a certain position in the list

```
public class LinkedList <E> implements List <E> {
    public E get(int index){
        Link current = goTo(index); //go to is a helper method that returns a pointer to a Link at position index
        E value = current.getValue(); //this is the source of the problem
        return value;

    }

}
```

The problem has something to with the generic type < E >, I don't fully understand how it works.

**Update**

I get the message: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to E` on the line indicated in the source.

Comment: What is the problem?  You forgot to tell us.

Comment: You are trying to implement List<E> but List<E> isn't an interface? Should you use extends List<E> instead?

Comment: List is an interface

Comment: The problem is with  E value = current.getValue();

Comment: I get the following message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to E

Comment: I think the line above your problem should be `Link<E> current = goTo(index);` but I can't know for sure without seeing the `goTo` method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should do like this:

```
Link<E> current = goTo(index);
```

as `Link current` (without `<E>`) pointed to list of Object class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide actual type to the type parameter when you implement it. A sample is given below.

```
package com.example.transformer;

/**
 * This represents the transformer contract to transform domain objects into
 * data transfer objects.
 *
 * @param <S>
 *            source to be transformed.
 * @param <T>
 *            result after the transformation.
 */
public interface Transformer<S, T> {
    T transform(S source);

}
```

Here is the implementation,

```
package com.example.transformer;

import com.example.domain.dto.OrderDetailsDTO;
import com.example.domain.dto.ProductDetailsDTO;
import com.example.domain.dto.ShippingDetailsDTO;

public class ProductDetailsDTOTOOrderDetailsDTOTransformer implements Transformer<ProductDetailsDTO, OrderDetailsDTO> {
    private ShippingDetailsDTO shippingInformation;

    public ProductDetailsDTOTOOrderDetailsDTOTransformer(ShippingDetailsDTO shippingInformation) {
        super();
        this.shippingInformation = shippingInformation;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderDetailsDTO transform(ProductDetailsDTO source) {
        return new OrderDetailsDTO(source.getName(), source.getUnitPrice() + shippingInformation.getCost(),
                source.getUnitPrice(), source.getCurrency(), source.getSoldBy(),
                shippingInformation.getCourierService(), shippingInformation.getAddress(),
                shippingInformation.getCost());
    }

}
```

Note that `S` and `T` is substituted with actual types `ProductDetailsDTO` and `OrderDetailsDTO` in the actual implementation. Iny your case it would be something like this.

```
public class LinkedList <YourType> implements List <E> {
   // your code goes here ...
}
```

Hope this helps. happy coding.

Comment: It does not have to be

Comment: If you leave it empty it will Object class. But still you can't pass E or so.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line: Link current = goTo(index);  You have to correct it to specify the type of Object you want to use: `Link <TypeOfObject> current = goTo(index);`  replace "TypeOfObject with the return type value of goTo method.  I am assuming it is an Integer, so if that is the case just replace `Link <TypeOfObject> current = goTo(index);` with `Link <Integer> current = goTo(index);`

Comment: What type value does goTo(index) returns? String? Integer? replace <TypeOfObject> with that return type of goTo method.